# Folder under webapp/content is not included in JHipster build

Tags: css, maven, spring-boot, jhipster

In my (rather basic) JHipster app, I have created a new folder called webapp/content/more

In that folder is some more CSS that I'm keeping separate for good reason.

When I run the app during development, all files are there and no issue. When I package the app for production with `mvnw -Pprod package -DskipTests`, the folder "more" is never put in the .WAR file so the extra CSS doesn't work.

I have no idea where to look for it (is it a pom.xml issue? Gulp issue?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `Gulpfile.js` that was generated by JHipster, you'll find that the `styles` task only processes `content/css` folder.

```
gulp.task('styles', [], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/css')
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Add your extra folder to it:

```
gulp.task('styles', [], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/css', config.app + 'content/more')
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Bu this is not enough, there are other gulp tasks to modify, just search for `css` in `Gulpfile.js` and `gulp` folder.

Comment: 100% correct. I also discovered that gulp puts all the files in target/www and that gets bundled in the war. The point basically is to get your files in that dir.